# Should we be using https to request soundcloud player embed?

Tags: ruby, soundcloud

My app which uses the Soundcloud API all the sudden stopped embedding widgets correctly today. I tried visiting the url which displays the widget by itself by following an embed link like so:
 http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F67072574&show_artwork=true&show_artwork=false&show_bpm=true&show_comments=true&download=true&maxwidth=440px&maxheight=160px&client_id=61628c1d0518b32eef1d403bb5a4a7a5

It was blank, and I noticed in the console this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/66977856?client_id=0f8fdbbaa21a9bd18210986a7dc2d72c&format=json. Origin http://w.soundcloud.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Checking other sites that embed the player, I saw the same issue (on Chrome).

I saw on their [status blog](http://status.soundcloud.com/post/35606705422/outage-update) that they had some server issues today, maybe this is a side effect, since everything worked properly until today.

Anyways, I also noticed that if I use https://w.soundcloud.com instead of 'http://' in the iframe src to embed the player displayed correctly. Therefore I worked around it by doing `puts embed_info['html'].gsub("http://w","https://w")` instead of the recommended `puts embed_info['html']`.

I would like to know whether I was supposed to use `https` in the first place, or this is something that needs to be fixed on their  end.

Comment: Whose blog? Fixed on whose end?

Comment: http://status.soundcloud.com/post/35606705422/outage-update -  and by "you", i mean soundcloud (they direct 'support' requests here and reply by watching SO questions tagged with 'soundcloud')

Comment: Rather than try to treat SO as the SoundCloud support forum or a conduit to SoundCloud's tech support, phrase your question as you would a normal Stack Overflow question. It will make more sense, and will encourage others to answer it.

Comment: This should be fixed by now, sorry for inconvenience.